# Has official 32bit support for cmake on Linux been dropped?

Tags: linux, cmake, 32-bit

I don't mean the version(s) provided by the various distributions but the binary from the official website.

I have an old VM running 32bit OpenSUSE 12.1 that is configured for a project I'm working on at work. I need to install WebKitGTK. The problem is that the cmake in the repositories is ancient 2.x, while WebKitGTK at least 3.6 (or similar). So I went to the official website and (my fault) without looking too much into it downloaded the 3.10 installation for Linux.

Upon executing the binary that was installed I got the error that the file could not be run. I checked the execution rights and it was fine. Then it struck me...I ran `file cmake` and got 64 instead of the required 32bit.

I went back to the website and all I could find were 32bit versions for Windows but none for Linux.

I can build it from source but just out of curiousity would like to know if support has been dropped. I was unable to find any information so far.

Comment: They provide binaries only for x86_64. But note that there isn't just Linux i386 and x86_64, e.g. Debian 9 is available for armel,armhf,arm64,mips,mips64el,mipsel,ppc64el,s390x in addition to i386 and x86_64. And CMake runs on all those platforms. It's just that they only provide pre-compiled binaries for one of those platforms for some reason.

Comment: As I've mentioned at the beginning I exclude the binaries provided by the specific distro. Do you know when and why support has been dropped?

Comment: You'll be able to get a more definitive answer on the reasoning why by e-mailing the package maintainer themself.

Comment: True, but that's not the point here. Just like Qt dropped official support of 32bit Linux and actually informed us why Kitware probably has posted somewhere when the decisions was taken. It will be "great" if all people interested in the reason send emails to this and that package maintainer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit support for CMake hasn't [been dropped](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/release/3.7.html#id12). They just don't provide binaries for it on their website as of [CMake 3.7.0](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-3-7-0-available-for-download/)